# fluentd install not working

Tags: installation, fluentd

I am trying to install td-agent on my linux machine and i am getting the following error.

Command:

```
curl -L https://td-toolbelt.herokuapp.com/sh/install-redhat-td-agent2.sh | sh
```

Output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
110   662  110   662    0     0   1870      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2916
This script requires superuser access to install rpm packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
curl: (28) connect() timed out!
error: https://packages.treasuredata.com/GPG-KEY-td-agent: import read failed(2).
Loaded plugins: security
packages.treasuredata.com/2/redhat/6Server/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
```

Is there any other way i can install?

Answer (score 0):

You have a connection problem.
Your IP may be banned.. Have you tried running the same command from another machine ?

According to Curl errors code:

```
CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT (28)

Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions.
```

You can create a local file, and paste the same code that you can find here

```
https://td-toolbelt.herokuapp.com/sh/install-redhat-td-agent2.sh
```

Then

```
chmod +x youscript.sh
```

and execute it.

Comment: i have tried in all machines. i could not even open http://packages.treasuredata.com/2/redhat/6Server/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml in browser also